# Undefined symbol after updating thc-hydra

Tags: symlink, libraries, hydra

I was using hydra without any issues until I decided to update it. Right now when I'm trying to run hydra I'm getting this error:

> hydra: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmongoc-1.0.so.0:
> undefined symbol: mongocrypt_kms_ctx_get_kms_provider

I tried reinstalling both hydra and libmongoc-1.0 and trying to find something in terms of symlinks but with no luck. What is exactly going and and how can I prevent it/handle in the future and mostly how to fix it right now?

Comment: With packet manager.

Comment: Yes, I am working on Kali.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: I purged all the dependencies of libmongoc and installed again, same with hydra. Now its working.

Answer (score 0):

I am also get this error after upgrade Hydra on Kali Linux. The solution is simple. Just install libmongoc-dev.

```
sudo apt install libmongoc-dev -y
```